# Import Data from Mysql to Neo4j using Pentaho kettle Spoon

Tags: sql-server, neo4j, etl, kettle

I was trying to migrate my mysql database to the Neo4j database. For that I was using `Pentaho Kettle`. I have also Downloaded plugins for the Neo4j in Kettle.

I am a beginner to kettle. I don't know the efficient way to bulk load data from mysql database to Neo4j, using kettle. I am thinking of doing as follows:

- First take input from table by writing sql query
- Then connect it to the Execute Script and create a cyper query for creating node and relationships corresponding to the table Schema.

Is there any better way of doing this? Because my database size is large. I have to write so many sql and cipher queries for importing my sql database to neo4j. I am looking for some bulk load feature in pentaho kettle spoon.

Here are the snapshots of my Transformations.

[Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOpPM.png)

[Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkeZh.png)

[Execute Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLWoQ.png)

My PDI version is `8.1.`

Comment: Last week, I wrote a post about that : https://www.bsimard.com/2018/09/03/kettle-neo4j.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. How you are loading the data from csv to neo4j output plugin?. In my database I have 40 tables. If I have to import data from them then I need to define node labels and properties which would be hectic. Is there any way it takes schema from the mysql database?

Comment: 1) In kettle there is a CSV component that reads your file and  streams the result to the next component (ex: the neo4j output). 2) There is nothing in kettle that will take your SQL db and load it as it in Neo4j... and in most use case you want to transform your SQL schema to a graph model (ex: put a field as a node)